# How to use make_early_stopping_hook in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

The [`make_early_stopping_hook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/make_early_stopping_hook) function was added to TensorFlow 1.10.0. I was wondering what would be the best practice in terms of accessing the evaluation/validation test result in the `should_stop_fn` function to decide whether to early stop the training process when using `train_and_evaluate()`.

Additionally, where should the "patience" mechanism be implemented?

It'd be great to see a working example using this new function.

Thanks!